# Windows store app - cryptographic key dialog

Tags: c#, javascript, windows-8, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I manage to create cryptographic key dialog in c#(code below) and I get status code of response message ok. That's fine.

But now i'm wondering, if this same think can be done in javascript project? I prefer to use javascript because I can't get ajax request to work in c#(I use it to access data from api).

```
        try
        {
            HttpClientHandler aHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
            aHandler.ClientCertificateOptions = ClientCertificateOption.Automatic;

            HttpClient aClient = new HttpClient(aHandler);
            HttpResponseMessage aResp = await aClient.GetAsync("https://www.somelink.com/"); //this is not the link I used
            txtBlock.Text = aResp.StatusCode.ToString();
        }
        catch (Exception theEx)
        {
            txtBlock.Text = theEx.Message;
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As i can see from this thread:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/0d005703-0ec3-4466-b389-663608fff053/using-client-side-certificates-in-windows-metro?forum=winappswithcsharp

Thursday, September 06, 2012 1:15 PM from Gaurav Mantri (MVP)

He tried to import certificate programly in C# and JS, in JS he managed to do this, so if he needs that certificate then he uses it, so loggically - it is possible in JS